# Integration of an EJB into a Framework?

Tags: java, ejb

Is there a way that you integrate an EJB into a Framework? I mean... this will be the framework's own EJB. This is a way of getting it started.

```
WeeklyTimerBean Tbean = WeeklyTimerBean.getInstance(); 
Tbean.bahbah(etc);
```

No JNDI connection and it will be on the server. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do? And what does "Framework" mean in this case? There's definitely a way to have a singleton (judging by your code sample) object not bound to JNDI - it's just not going to be an EJB :-)

Comment: I'm trying to integrate an ejb into framework. Meaning that the framework will be able to call the bean. I've thought about using javabeans or java timers. The only problem is that the last time i used java timers. It bugged my program even when I took it out. I'm trying to see if there is a way to call an ejb without using its architecture. Like deploying it as a .jar file or with a .war file. I'm just trying to see if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Also to let you know. That I will be calling it from a servlet. Not a regular java application. Being used for web programming

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Crain, you cannot deny the fact that a specification exists for EJBs.

If it's inconvenient for you, you can wrap it in utility classes.

Maybe something like [JBoss Seam](http://jboss.com/products/seam) is what you want/need? Maybe not?